# What is this kind of parsing?

Tags: linux, bash

What is this kind of argument parsing?

```
$RES="${SOME_VAR##foo/}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`${SOME_VAR##foo/}` - ***bash*** variable substitution.

It search for match against the pattern `foo/` from the start of the string (`SOME_VAR` variable's value) and truncates the left part including the pattern.

Example:

```
s="foo/some#foo#textfoo/textlast"
echo ${s##foo/}
some#foo#textfoo/textlast
```

---

***Note***, this `${s##foo/}` is equivalent to `${s#foo/}`, cause it searches only for the 1st occurrence of the pattern `foo/` from the start of the string.

While this `${s##*foo/}` will truncate the left part till the ***last*** matching pattern(inclusive)

```
echo ${s##*foo/}
textlast
```

Comment: So basically it removes the everything up to and including the first occurence of `foo/` right?

Comment: @Jim, right, basically `#` matches from left side, `%` - from right side(from the end)

Answer (score 0):

According to `man bash`:

> **Parameter Expansion**
>          The `$' character introduces parameter expansion, command substitution, or arithmetic expansion.  The parameter name or symbol to be expanded may be enclosed in braces, which are optional but serve to protect the variable to be expanded from characters immediately following it which could be interpreted as part of the name.
>
> **${parameter#word}**
>    **${parameter##word}**
>    **Remove matching prefix pattern.**
>   The word is expanded to produce a pattern just as in pathname expansion.  If the pattern matches the beginning of the value of parameter, then  the  result  of the  expansion  is  the expanded  value  of  parameter  with  the shortest matching pattern (the ``#'' case) or the longest matching pattern (the ``##'' case) deleted.  If parameter is @ or *, the pattern removal operation is applied to each positional parameter in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.  If parameter is an array variable subscripted with @ or *, the pattern removal operation is applied to each member of the array in turn, and  the expansion is the resultant list.